# Enabling Deep Linking In Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, deep-linking

I am trying to enable deep linking in my android app using [this official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html).I am not able to understand where and how to add URI under data element. What would be the value of URI for my app. Is it referring to package name?Do I have to add intent filter tag for each android name activity? Any one example would be enough to make things clear. Please suggest.

**My Manifest file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.EvlHealthPlans" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.ConHealthInsurance" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.HealthPlanNetworks" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.ProvCompensation" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.CdphpPlans" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.HmoPlans" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.PpoPlans" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.ProviderTypes" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.UtilizationManagement" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.EDIConcept" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.ClaimProcessing" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.CobraHippa" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.GovernmentPrograms"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is your url? for deeplinking?

Answer (score 0):

Add following `intent filter` in the `activity` tag which you want to launch while `deep linking`.

```
<activity android:name="com.myapp.praveen.healthcareit.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/appx"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

where your url is like `http://www.example.com?appx=45`. So here scheme is http or https. If you want both then add two intent filters, one with `http` and another with `https`. Then `pathPrefix` is the `url parameters` you want to identify. Not `pathprefix` can be empty or `*`. And finally host is your website address to be deep linked.

Comment: what would be the host name for my app? Please let me know.

Comment: @Praveenks For what url you want to deep link?

Answer (score 0):

No need filter to all activity need only for the activity which you want to invoke from deep link url.  in manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="yourpackagename"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/actioncolor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />



            <data android:scheme="schemename"
                android:host="hostname" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

your URI will be schemename://hostname?hereextraparametersifyouwant
here you get the full example with steps
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-deep-linking/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex

Comment: Can you please let me know the hostname for my app ?

Comment: That's up to you what you want put that